# merging sorted list of list members if neighbors are equal

Tags: python

If I have the following list of lists,

```
[[212, -217], [210, -488], [210, 46]]
```

I would like to merge them so that the second member of lists whose first members are equal are added, and the entries merged, so the output would be:

```
[[212, -217], [210, -442]]
```

What is the best way to do this? My attempt is below, but this fails because y appears to always be empty:

```
d = [[212, -217], [210, -488], [210, 46]]
from itertools import groupby
ret = [[x, sum(y)] for x, y in groupby(d, key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Comment: You should get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`.

Comment: Yes I do. Why is that? Shouldn't `y` be the grouped members of the second positions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close you can use [*`zip`*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to zip the grouped numbers then use [*`map`*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function to apply the `set` and `sum` on your pairs :

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [map(sum,map(set,zip(*g))) for _,g in groupby(sorted(d, key=itemgetter(0)),key=itemgetter(0))]
[[210, -442], [212, -217]]
```

But as a more **pythonic** way you can use [*`collections.defaultdict`*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic=defaultdict(int)
>>> for i,j in d:
...   dic[i]+=j
... 
>>> dic.items()
[(210, -442), (212, -217)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just use a dictionary for this:

```
srclist = [[212, -217], [210, -488], [210, 46]]

dstdict = {}
for key, val in srclist:
    dstdict[key] = dstdict.get(key, 0) + val

dstlist = [[key, val] for key, val in dstdict.iteritems()]

print dstlist # [[210, -442], [212, -217]]
```

It’s not quite as elegant as a one-liner, but it does the trick and I think it makes it clear exactly what the code is doing.

If you want to preserve the order of the original list, iterate through the original list looking at the first entry, and append to the new list based on the value in the dictionary:

```
dstlist = []

used_keys = []
for key, val in srclist:
    # If we've already added this key to the dstlist, then don't add it again
    if key in used_keys:
        continue
    else:
        dstlist.append([key, dstdict[key]])
        used_keys.append(key)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
l = [[212, -217], [210, -488], [210, 46]]
d = OrderedDict()
for i in l:
    if i[0] in d:
        d[i[0]] += i[1]
    else:
        d[i[0]] = i[1]

l = [[k, v] for k, v in d.items()]
```